# Buscando valor minimo por tramos, se puede?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy en la busqueda de como poder obtener el número mínimo por tramo, en este caso por el Code A, como muestran en las tablas. La tabla superior es la obtenida por DataFrame segun este codigo.

```
df_dm = (pd.DataFrame(sh_dist, columns=['Code A','Code B','Xa','Ya','Xb','Yb','Distance' ]))
print (df_dm)
group_dm = df_dm.groupby(by=['Code A','Distance']).min()
print (group_dm)
```

Los print son los mostrado en las tablas adjuntadas.

Obteniendo la segunda tabla. Son doce datos, según mi observación debería ser tres datos los resultados:

A1 B5  6.40

A2 B2 10.00

A2 B3 10.0

Por lo que puedo apreciar, el algoritmo discrimina ya que el dato B3 lo elimina (por cierto son puntos coordenados).

Me han sugerido que utilice lambda, apply y filter, pero recien estoy empezando y se me hace díficil, agradeceré cualquier ayuda para poder llegar a mi objetivo, obtener los mínimos por los tramos (A1, A2) sin discriminar. Estos tramos podrían llegar a 100 (A1, A2, A3, ..... A100)

Desde ya gracias

Datos de entrada

```
Code A Code B    Xa    Ya    Xb    Yb   Distance
0      A1     B1  12.0  60.0  18.0  70.0  11.661904
1      A1     B2  12.0  60.0  25.0  50.0  16.401219
2      A1     B3  12.0  60.0  25.0  70.0  16.401219
3      A1     B4  12.0  60.0  12.0  75.0  15.000000
4      A1     B5  12.0  60.0   8.0  65.0   6.403124
5      A1     B6  12.0  60.0  15.0  50.0  10.440307
6      A2     B1  25.0  60.0  18.0  70.0  12.206556
7      A2     B2  25.0  60.0  25.0  50.0  10.000000
8      A2     B3  25.0  60.0  25.0  70.0  10.000000
9      A2     B4  25.0  60.0  12.0  75.0  19.849433
10     A2     B5  25.0  60.0   8.0  65.0  17.720045
11     A2     B6  25.0  60.0  15.0  50.0  14.142136
```

Datos salida

```
                Code B    Xa    Ya    Xb    Yb
Code A Distance                                
A1     6.403124      B5  12.0  60.0   8.0  65.0
       10.440307     B6  12.0  60.0  15.0  50.0
       11.661904     B1  12.0  60.0  18.0  70.0
       15.000000     B4  12.0  60.0  12.0  75.0
       16.401219     B2  12.0  60.0  25.0  50.0
A2     10.000000     B2  25.0  60.0  25.0  50.0
       12.206556     B1  25.0  60.0  18.0  70.0
       14.142136     B6  25.0  60.0  15.0  50.0
       17.720045     B5  25.0  60.0   8.0  65.0
       19.849433     B4  25.0  60.0  12.0  75.0
```

Comment: ok, pero no veo donde está la opcion de editar la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo que lo que realmente buscas es filtrar las filas que en cada grupo definido por `Code A` tienen como distancia la distancia mínima para ese grupo.

En tal caso una forma muy simple es agrupar solo por `Code A` y mediante `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.transform` obtener una Serie en la que cada fila sea el mínimo para ese grupo:

> ```
> >>> df_dm.groupby('Code A')["Distance"].transform(min)
>
> 0      6.403124
> 1      6.403124
> 2      6.403124
> 3      6.403124
> 4      6.403124
> 5      6.403124
> 6     10.000000
> 7     10.000000
> 8     10.000000
> 9     10.000000
> 10    10.000000
> 11    10.000000
> ```

Hecho esto basta con aplicar un filtro boleano para quedarnos con las filas cuya distancia es la distancia mínima por grupo:

```
min_dist = df_dm[df_dm["Distance"] == df.groupby('Code A')["Distance"].transform(min)]
```

> ```
> >>> min_dist
>
>     Code A    Code B    Xa      Ya      Xb      Yb    Distance
> 4   A1        B5      12.0    60.0     8.0    65.0    6.403124
> 7   A2        B2      25.0    60.0     25.0   50.0    10.000000
> 8   A2        B3      25.0    60.0     25.0   70.0    10.000000
> ```

Comment: Gracias es lo que buscaba, a leer sobre filtros boleanos